# how to compare arraylist with String whilst ignoring capitalization?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, ignore-case

I am getting an error saying that `.equalsIgnoreCase` is undefined for the type `Dog`, is there any way to find a `String` in the `ArrayList` while ignoring capitalization without using `.equalsIgnoreCase`?

```
public static int findDog(String toFind, ArrayList<Dog> dogs)
      {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < dogs.size() ; i++)
        {
          if (dogs.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(toFind))
          {
            return i;
          }
        }
        return -1;           
      }
```

`Dog` has a public constructor like this:

```
public Dog(String name, double age, double weight)
```

Comment: How are you supposed to compare a `Dog` and a `String`?  Is there some string variable _in_ `Dog` that you're trying to compare?

Comment: perhaps you want `dogs.get(i).getName()` or `dogs.get(i).toString()` to compare against a String, I guess representing name or some other attribute?

Comment: Dog is the constructor which is public Dog(String name, double age, double weight)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compare a `Dog` with a `String`, assuming `Dog` has some `String` property then you can do it with this:

**Example:**

```
if (dogs.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(toFind)){
       return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes Dog has a String property, sorry for not specifying that in the question!

Comment: @meli it's fine, just updated your description to say so. you need not be sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

add .getName() after get(i) in if loop

Like:  if (dogs.get(i)..getName().equalsIgnoreCase(toFind))

Answer (score 0):

See, `.equalsIgnoreCase logic` will work with Dog absolutely fine but not like you did it. Here's what you need to do.

Let's say you want to say `2 dogs are same if they have same Name`.

Then Modify your Dog class as shown below :

```
public class Dog implements Comparable<Dog> {

   private String name;
   private double age;
   private double weight;

    public Dog(String name, double age, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(double age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dog anotherDogToCompare) {
        return this.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(anotherDogToCompare.getName().toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Now, whenever , you want to compare 2 dogs , the above `compareTo` if it gives `0` then 2 Dogs are same else not same. Note that I am assuming 2 Dogs are same if they have same Name.

If that is not the equality criteria , no need to worry. All you need to change is code inside `compareTo` according to your logic. [Read More](https://dzone.com/articles/java-comparable-interface-in-five-minutes)

Okay. Now you code will be :

```
public static int findDog(String toFind, ArrayList<Dog> dogs)
      {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < dogs.size() ; i++)
        {
          if (dogs.get(i).compareTo(toFind) == 0) // Only this changes
          {
            return i;
          }
        }
        return -1;           
      }
```